# Proving the Jordan extension of $\tilde{m}$ defined on a ring does not depend on choice of underlying rectangular coordinate system

Tags: measure-theory

The problem I'm trying to solve is

Let $\tilde{m}$ be the measure defined on the ring $R$ of all elementary sets (i.e, all finite unions of disjoint rectangles with the sides parallel to the coordinate axes). Let $\mu$ be the Jordan extension of $\tilde{m}$. Prove that $\mu$ does not depend on the particular choice of the underlying rectangular coordinate system.

In other words, I need to prove that $\mu$ as well as the corresponding ring of all Jordan measurable sets does not change if all the sets in $R$ are subjected to the same shift or rigid rotation.

I'm just not even really sure how to start.

I know that if A is an elementary set, and if A is equal to the union of pairwise disjoint rectangles $P_k$, then the measure of A is

\begin{align*}
\tilde{m}(A) = \sum_k m(P_k)
\end{align*}

where $m(p_k)$ is the measure of the rectangle P (where P is equal to the union of $P_k$'s)

A set A is said to be Jordan measurable if given and $\epsilon>0$ There are sets A', A'' $\in$ $R$ such that $A'\subset A \subset A''$ and $\tilde{m}(A''-A')<\epsilon$.